# How to do a restoration in MySQL using a backup created with --hex-blob option?

Tags: mysql

I created a backup using the statement

```
mysqldump --hex-blob -h localhost -u the_database_user -p database_name > /location/of/the/backup.sql
```

Now, I want to use the backup for restoring it. Knowing that it has `--hex-blob`, what is the right way of restoring it?

Comment: try this http://serverfault.com/questions/218887/error-importing-large-mysql-dump-file-which-includes-binary-blobs-in-windows

Comment: using what? the second answer?

Comment: Have you tried just restoring it normally?  `--hex-blob` creates dump files that are larger because blobs are exported as [hex-encoded, quoted literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/hexadecimal-literals.html), but that should be fully compatible for a normal restore.